# interface com.sun.xml.ws.developer.WSBindingProvider is not visible from class loader

Tags: java, spring, jax-ws, classloader

In tomcat web container spring listens to session and executes a destroy-method on a "session-scoped" bean, that invokes a web-service.

sometimes this strange exception is raised:

```
 interface com.sun.xml.ws.developer.WSBindingProvider is not visible from class loader
```

What can this mean?

Comment: Without more detail, such as a complete stack trace, it's going to be hard for anybody to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

This has to be a jar conflict issue. Check the below link if it helps:
[generated-client-error](http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/Generated-client-gets-error-WSBindingProvider-is-not-visible-from-class-loader-when-jaxws-rt-jar-is-t-td4269669.html)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue "interface com.sun.xml.ws.developer.WSBindingProvider is not visible from class loader", the same issue has been envounterd when developping 3rd party h2h connection under the GlassFish Server v2.1 . But after moving the 3rd party related jar from ".../lib/ext” into the “.../lib” level this issue possible to be rectified.